# Export multiple file types from single source entry file type

Tags: webpack

I'm attempting to:
1. take a set of constants from a single JS source.
2. pull the file's data into memory.
3. export a single CSS file, and HTML file with the data injected into a template.

The JS file looks like a few dozen lines of this kind of thing:

`export const ThemeColor = '#b4d455';`

I have tried multiple ways with Webpack 1 and Webpack 2, PostCSS, PostHTML, ExtractTextPlugin, html-webpack-plugin, and more.

Here's a PostCSS AST playground demonstrating the CSS and HTML part: 
http://astexplorer.net/#/XTaqkcrrLy/4

It doesn't seem like it's possible to do.